# Can't access XML with Linq

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse the following XML file and nothing I do results in anything but the root or the firstnode.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
     <Report {attributes}>
         <table1>
             <Detail_Collection>
                <Detail {attributes} />
                <Detail {attributes} />
                <Detail {attributes} />
             </Detail_Collection>
         </table1>
     </Report>
```

I am trying to get a list of *Detail* so that I can get the attribute values, but everything I have tried results in no data. My latest attempt is this one...

```
var xml= XDocument.Load(FileDetails.FullName);
var xml1 = XDocument.Parse(xml.Root.FirstNode.ToString());
var xml3 = from e in custs.Root.Elements("Detail") select e;
var xml4 = from e in xml1.Elements("Detail") select e;
```

Different attempt

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(FileDetails.FullName);
var root = xml.Root;
var els = root.Descendants("Detail");
```

The above displays in the immediate window:

> root.Descendants("Detail")
>   {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.GetDescendants}
>       name: null
>       self: false
>       System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator.Current:
>   null
>       System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current:
>   null

The problem is with the attributes in the Report element:

```
<Report p1:schemaLocation="Info_x0020_Tickets_x0020_Entered http://domain/ReportServer?%2fInfo+Reporting%2fInfo+Tickets+Entered&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs%3aFormat=XML&rs%3aSessionID=vcvb0p452bb3na45havjes55&rc%3aSchema=True" Name="Info Tickets Entered" textbox9="1247" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Info_x0020_Tickets_x0020_Entered">
```

This is from SQL Server Reporting Server, I'll have to remove one by one and find the culprit.

**This is the final solution to this problem**
There may be a better way, but once the data is loaded you cannot easily remove the namespace.

```
//load the original document
var xml = XDocument.Load(FileDetails.FullName);
//remove all the superflouos data attributes
xml.Root.RemoveAttributes();
//turn into a string
var content = xml.Root.ToString();
//remove the official namespace, there is no easy way to remove the namespace after document has been loaded, so we'll replace it
var newXmlContent = content.Replace("<Report xmlns=\"Info_x0020_Tickets_x0020_Entered\">", "<Report>");
//parse the updated string into a workable document
var newXml = XDocument.Parse(newXmlContent).Root;
```

This returns a new XML document that can be processed normally.

Comment: What are the attributes?

Comment: The problem lies in the attributes for *Report*

Comment: What are the attributes in the XML?

Comment: It was the extra XMLNS attribute at the end. However, if I delete the first one (and the corresponsing p1 declaration, it doesn't work). In this case, I can just delete the attributes completely. Your answer below would be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `custs.Root.Elements("Detail")` will return all `<Detail>` elements that are *direct* children of the root (`<Report>`) element.

You need to call `Descendants`.

Alternatively, you can call

```
custs.Root.Element("table1").Element("Detail_Collection").Elements("Detail")
```

**EDIT**: Your elements are probably in a namespace (`xmlns="..."` in the root).
You need to ask XLINQ for the elements in the correct namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "Info_x0020_Tickets_x0020_Entered";
var els = root.Descendants(ns + "Detail");
```

Comment: It was the namespacing - I had two namespaces, I deleted the second one and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml= XDocument.Load(FileDetails.FullName);
var detailList = xml.Root.Decendants("Detail");
```

This will give you an enumerable collection of `XElements` that are all the `Detail` elements in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?> 
 <Report foo=""bar"">
     <table1>
         <Detail_Collection>
            <Detail foo=""bar"" />
            <Detail foo=""bar"" />
            <Detail foo=""bar"" />
         </Detail_Collection>
     </table1>
 </Report>";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        foreach (var desc in doc.Root.Descendants("Detail"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(desc.Attribute("foo").Value);
        }
```